# Rewrite rules with a broad match plus exclusions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have redesigned my site and the way the links are structured, they used to be structured like so

```
www.domain.com/firstvariable/secondvariable
```

Now they are like

```
www.domain.com/cat/firstvariable_secondvariable.html
```

I could have a rule which redirect everthing after / to /mp3/ but the rule i already have to redirect to /mp3 from the actual mp3.php gets overiden by using the / rule

It would also affect my other pages that have 1 "separator" and 2 variables, how can i stop this?

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^mp3/(.*)-(.*)/?.html$ mp3.php?artist=$1&song=$2 [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /mp3/$1_$2.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Post the other rule as well. The one you fear would get interfered.

Comment: So, you want to have the same pattern `^(.*)/(.*)$` go to two different rules, is that right? Sometimes its should go to /mp3... and sometimes to /cat... ? If that is the case, you will have to either change that logic, or find something that separates the two cases.

Comment: No cat was the example, the actual page is /mp3

Comment: So, for `/MJ/Thriller` do you actually have `/mp3/MJ_Thriller.html`? If yes, then why do you have the `mp3.php` rule?